# how to include javascript inside html

Tags: javascript, php, html

Sorry for asking this silly question.

I got stuck to include a *javascript* file in my *html* page in a *php* project. when I try this it works fine-

`<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>`

But when I want to load the **script.js** file from my **js** directory it does not work. I tried-

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>`

**N.B:** I have my **js** folder in the same **myproject** directory alongside my **index.php** and **script.js** is located inside the **js** folder.

Comment: When you load this page that the script is not loading on, what is the URL?

Comment: as I am running on my local machine the url is - http://localhost/myproject/index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are subfolders in your project, to have js/script.js working you have to set your base path in your index.php like

```
echo '<base href="http://localhost/myproject/">';
```

then the following line as a normal html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can’t. PHP doesn’t execute Javascript code. Since Javascript and PHP are both scripting languages. You can use Jquery or AJAX or something like this to run js code

```html
<script> 
 var my_javascript_var = "<?php echo 'some value I need on the client side' ; ?>"; 
alert (my_javascript_var ); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be access denied reading js folder or ..anything really. ...but the best you can do - open developer tools in your browser (hit F12 on Chrome), go to tab "Network" and refresh the page - you should see the reason why it doesnt load- status code will tell you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I was calling my script in `<head>` tag of html which did not work for me. But calling it before closing of `<body>` tag worked!

Don't know why. Can anyone explain?

And obviously thanks everyone.